# Why does the code snippets output as this?

Tags: javascript, function, closures, lexical-scope

```
const phrase = 'Hello';

if (true) {
  const user = 'John';

  var sayHi = () => {
    console.log(`${phrase}, ${user}`);
  };
}

sayHi(); // Hello, John
console.log(user); // ReferenceError: user is not defined
```

user and sayHi both defined inside `if` block, but sayHi is available outside the block, in the same time user is not. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: And read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope

Comment: Thank you guys. I got it. I found this from https://javascript.info/closure#function-in-if . I think the author made an mistake, the result is not an error. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use `var` to define a variable, the variable is hoisted - which means its declaration is moved to the top of the current scope.
However this is not true for scoped variables that are created using `let`/`const`, where the variables are only defined in the scope they were created

Answer (score 0):

```
const phrase = 'Hello';
const user = 'John';

if (true) {
  var sayHi = () => {
    console.log(`${phrase}, ${user}`);
  };
}

sayHi(); // Hello, John
console.log(user); // This will work now, this answer is similar to @Saurabh Agrawal
```

Answer (score 0):

A block scope is the area within if, switch conditions or for and while loops. Generally speaking, whenever you see {curly brackets}, it is a block. In ES6, `const` and `let` keywords allow developers to declare variables in the block scope, which means those variables exist only within the corresponding block.

In you program the `user` is scoped constant which is only accessible inside `if` block.
That's that why you are getting `undefined` when you use outside the `if` block.

See this [**reference**](https://dev.to/sandy8111112004/javascript-introduction-to-scope-function-scope-block-scope-d11).

Answer (score 0):

The variable was created using 'const' keyword inside the scope of the if statement, in simple words it was created inside the opening '{'  and closing '}' so it can only be accessed inside the brackets, because 'const' and 'let' have block scope. [Check out the full explanation here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)